# Stuck importing CSV data into Highcharts diagram

Tags: javascript, html, css, import

I am trying to draw a chart in a HTML page using Highcharts with data from a CSV file, more specifically i'm trying to replicate the official example (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module), to no avail. When i load the page, the chart is not present and i get a "Highchart Error 13" error in the console (https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/13/). I tried with and without the "renderto:" line and in both cases it didn't work.

Here is my HTML code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Highcharts Test</title>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS code :

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    data: {
        enablePolling: true,
        csvURL: 'graph.csv'
    },
    renderto: "container",
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Units'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my CSV data imported as a CSS code snippet :

```css
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Joe,86,76,79,77
Janet,3,16,13,15
```

I double-checked every file name and found no errors. I am using Mozilla Firefox 96.0.3 64 bits and Windows 10 1607 14393.1944 .